# Android: Couldn't add widget

Tags: android, widget

I'm creating a launcher, and in my activity where I host the widgets, I followed this amazing tutorial http://coderender.blogspot.com.eg/2012/01/hosting-android-widgets-my.html (I believe it's the only one out there) and I got to add some widgets to my activity, but not all of them get added successfully, some widgets (As Digital Clock, Dual Clock , etc. etc.) shows a grey bar in their place on my activity with inner message "Couldn't add widget", some widgets as (Netflix widget) appears successfully on my activity for a second or less then it shows the same grey bar in its place with the same message.

I tried to search google but in vein, I even cleared Netflix app cash but still in vein.

I'm testing on Note 3 with Android 5.0 ... Using

```
compileSdkVersion 26

buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
```

**Is there required permissions that I have to add in my AndroidManifest.xml for my activity to host widgets? Could this be the source behind this problem?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Anyone has a clue what could be the reason? I kept investigating thinking that maybe something deletes these widget which causes this effect, but I checked and they are not deleted, they are just not previewed.

Comment: Knowing that other launchers as Microsoft Launcher previews them correctly, so they are not a damaged widgets.

Comment: And I compared my code against Android Launcher source code and there's no noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

One of the scenarios where the widget couldn't be added is that the image displayed on the widget doesn't fits in the minHeight and minWidth mentioned in the app-widget_provider xml file.

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/app_name"
    android:minHeight="150dp"
    android:minWidth="150dp"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">

</appwidget-provider>
```

My fix was the equal the minHeight and minWidth as the dispayed image was a square.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173740/appcompat-breaks-launcher-widget-ability-couldnt-find-any-view-using-error-v) is similar to your question.

@dasfima's answer in that question fixed the issue for me:

> change the context of the manager and host to be the application context instead of the activity context.

```
AppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
mAppWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(getApplicationContext(), APPWIDGET_HOST_ID);
```

It works like a charm in my application.